Windows 10: how to prevent the mouse wheel scrolling horizontally
In Windows 10 (but generically in any Windows version AFAIK) if you turn the mouse wheel inside a window which can be scrolled horizontally (eg. an Explorer window showing a horizontal scrollbar but not a vertical one), the result is that the content is scrolled horizontally.
I find this behavior very annoying and counter-intuitive, so I was trying to disable it, but I found no way.
Setting WheelScrollChars = 0 in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop unfortunately has no effect.
Is there any way to prevent horizontal scrolling in such cases ?

This question has nothing to do with programming. It should be asked on [su] instead.
